# Visual Studio .NET error: Form does not contain Dispose(bool) method

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dispose

Occasionally Visual Studio (2005, 2008, 2010) will lose its mind, and get confused by a WinForm:

**SplashForm.cs:**

```
public partial class SplashForm : Form
{
   ...
```

**SplashForm.Designer.cs:**

```
partial class SplashForm
{
   ...
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
         components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
   }
   ...
```

It will complain:

- `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)`
  'Dispose(bool)' has no suitable method to override
- `base.Dispose(disposing);`
  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose`

It's complaining about code that **it** generated.

It's been too long (3 years) since i dealt with Visual Studio, so i've forgotten the trick to get Visual Studio's head out of its own assembly.

What's the trick to get it going again?

Comment: This is what happens with partial classes and you rename only one part.  Now the designer part doesn't have a base class anymore with a Dispose method that can be overridden.  Rename the other part as well.  Use Refactor next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue today and found this question. I managed to fix it and while the post is old (2 years old now) I think it is always good to answer it with the solution I found:

- **My Scenario**: I created a form in the wrong directory
- **The result**: The namespace was different from the namespaces of the other forms.
- **The cause**: In my specific case, this was caused because I changed the `<Form>.Designer.cs` namespace so that it matched the rest of the forms Namespace. **But** I didn't change the `<Form>.cs` namespace and that was my mistake.

So, if you're having this error, make sure both your namespaces from the `<Form>.Designer.cs` and `<Form>.cs` match.

Comment: Almost the same in my case, I was moving the whole project into another namespace and forgot to change the namespace for <Form>.Designer.cs. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Well i fixed it.

i excluded:

- `SplashForm.cs`
- `SplashForm.Designer.cs`
- `SplashForm.resx`

from the project, and moved the files to another folder.

Then i created a *new* form, called `SplashForm`, and copied the contents of:

- `SplashForm.cs`
- `SplashForm.Designer.cs`
- `SplashForm.resx`

from the backup copies.